# Angular 5 Module provide different services

Tags: angular

I have the next problem and maybe you can help me to solve it.

I have a Menu Component that requires service that will provide menu-items:

```
export class MenuComponent {
  currentLang = 'en';

  constructor(
    public menuService: MenuService,
    public translate: TranslateService) {
  }

  addMenuItem(): void {
    this.menuService.add({
      state: 'menu',
      name: 'MENU',
      type: 'sub',
      icon: 'trending_flat',
      children: [
        {state: 'menu', name: 'MENU'},
        {state: 'timeline', name: 'MENU'}
      ],
      roles: []
    });
  }
}
```

This component is included into the module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
    MenuComponent,
    ...
  ],
  exports:      [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class PrimerModule {

}
```

Then I have 2 independent components that requires this module and menu components (with different routes).

```
 {path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', component: DashboardRootComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
```

and

```
  {path: 'event/:id/management',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', component: DashboardEventComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
```

DashboardRootComponent and DashboardEventComponent are provided by different modules DashboardRootModule and DashboardEventModule.

I want to include different MenuServices into DashboardRootModule  and DashboardEventModule to be able to display different menu. How can I do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you register the service in each component instead of in the module, you will get independent instances of the service instead of a shared instance.

See this in the Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-add-other-providers-to-a-module-or-a-component

Comment: Thanks, but when I inject directly to the components I have exceptions:




ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MenuComponent -> MenuService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MenuComponent -> MenuService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MenuService!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MenuComponent -> MenuService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MenuComponent -> MenuService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MenuService!

Comment: How are you injecting it into the component? By adding it to the `providers` array?

Comment: Yes, with array

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code? Or add it to a plunker/stackblitz?